# How to convert sqlite dates to a date in R

Tags: r, sqlite, lubridate

I am working with a sqlite database table. I have pulled the data into R using the RSQLite package. One of the columns holds a date. Sqlite is storing it as a Real number, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. (e.g.1264896000). Any ideas on how to convert this to a valid date in R? I tried the following

```
as.POSIXct(1264896000,origin = "-4714-11-24")
```

However, this doesn't work as the character string in not in a standard form. Any ideas?

Comment: I question your understanding of the origin of SQLite dates. The triple zeroes at the end suggest these are seconds or milliseconds since a more recent origin, probably the typical POSIX origin of 1970-01-01

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I got thrown off by the SQLite documentation which lists the above date. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: That SQLite table was apparently stored as integer (rather than real) which has the standard POSIX origin. If it had been a real number, you might have needed to use `julian` with the other origin as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested my theory that your claim about the origin was unlikely. The theory that these are POSIX date-times (origin= 1970-01-01 and times in seconds)  seems supported by experiment.

```
> as.POSIXct(1264896000,origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2010-01-30 16:00:00 PST"
```

Comment: You can also try this: `library(sqldf); sqldf("SELECT datetime(1264896000, 'unixepoch') date")`

Comment: I was now reading datetimes from SQLite3 and the format was e.g. "1495734240000", i.e., apparently in milliseconds from the origin. So the way to convert it was `as.POSIXct(datetime/1000, origin = "1970-01-01")`